# Facebook like scroll down and searching/adding

Tags: sql, ajax, database, responsive-design

I am working on enhancing the a search functionality of a website.

The current search is working as

1.reading all the rows from the database

2.find keywords from each rows and return the result.

The problem is it is too slow and it has to prepare all the data in the backend which mean read all the data from different database and put them to html.

The solution comes to my mind is:

1. show partial search results (like 10) which means as long as it find enough result in the databse it will stop reading and searching rows.
2. once user scroll down the page, using ajax to trigger another process of searching

My questions is:

1. Is it a good way(possible way) to do that?
2. Any tutorial source I should look up.

i know it is kinda abstract question, but I need advice for this.

Thanks in advance.

Update my research:
https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll

this jquery lib can do the front end job

Comment: First, I suggest that you see if the slowness is due to backend processing or page loading.  If it's page loading, and you want to use the Facebook approach of adding as you scroll, remember that at some point you'll have to stop.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thanks for the advice. The reason I think it is caused by both backend process and page loading (Maybe more backend process) is that the search is happening in php, not database search(like % wildcard). It is working on small amount of data and the whole system is freezing on large amount of data.

Comment: @DanBracuk I like the way you define it, facebook like scroll and searching/adding